# Problems with parallax header in react native

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native

Trying to write a parallax scroll view in react native. First off, this is what I have so far:

[image]

The only problem, as you can see in the GIF above, is that, children in scroll view disappear at the red line, which is the `ScrollView`'s original top border position. I've tried to change the top border position but it doesn't work, continue to read. The height of the parallax header is `170px`, after `100px` scrolled, the image stops going up, therefore, the sticky header height is `70px`

Here is the code for the GIF above:

```
const parallaxHeaderHeight = 170;
const headerHeight = 70;
const headerDiff = parallaxHeaderHeight - headerHeight;    // 100px

class ParallaxScrollView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.scrollY = new Animated.Value(0);    // How many pixels scrolled
    }

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Animated.Image
            source={{ uri: '...' }}
            style={{
                width: ..., height: ...,
                transform: [
                    {
                        translateY: this.scrollY.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [-1, 0, headerDiff, headerDiff + 1],
                            outputRange: [0, 0, -headerDiff, -headerDiff]
                        })
                    },
                    {
                        scale: this.scrollY.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [-1, 0, 1],
                            outputRange: [1.005, 1, 1]
                        })
                    }
                ]
            }}
        />
        <Animated.ScrollView
            scrollEventThrottle={1}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
                [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } }],
                { useNativeDriver: true }
            )}
        >
            // Then, render children here
        </Animated.ScrollView>
    </View>
}
```

Then, I've tried to transform the top border of scroll view, but this happens:

[image]

Look at the first child of the scroll view, `0`, it disappears when I've scrolled `100px`, but what I want is for it to stay viewable when scrolling the first `100px`. I know why this is happening, but I can't find a solution. How should I modify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: This problem can be solved with a 'hacky' solution, but is not recommended, for reasons listed below.

First of all, the solution is - Add an initial padding to the scroll view's children (`Looking at the code snippet in the question and adding this part to it`):

```
...
<Animated.Image
    ...
    style={{
        ...
        position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1,
        top: 0, left: 0, right: 0,
        height: parallaxHeaderHeight       // which is 170px in my case
        ...
    }}
    ...
/>
<Animated.ScrollView
    ...
    contentContainerStyle={{ paddingTop: parallaxHeaderHeight }}
    ...
>
    ...
</Animated.ScrollView>
...
```

This gives me:

[image]

The flaw is that, part of the scroll bar is hidden behind the image header due to the fact that the header has `position = absolute` and `zIndex = 1`. But if the scroll bar is not important, then never mind, this 'hacky' solution is just fine and doesn't cause any performance issue