# Parallax/ animated Header on react native with scrollView onScroll

Tags: react-native

With this reference
[Problems with parallax header in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001008/problems-with-parallax-header-in-react-native)

The only solution found is just an hack that hide you refreshcomponent because contentContainerStyle don't interact with the refreshcomponent.

So, the only solution is to move the scrollview component, but moving it while you are scrolling is pretty laggy and staggering.
Any solution?
This is pretty common case, i mean..Facebook app and Twitter app have both this this type of home screen!

and example animation is:
[animated header from play store app home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxsuy.gif)

added snack: 
[snack esample of header animation](https://snack.expo.io/@bonobomagno/animation-header-special)

as you see, on Android, scrolling up and down start to stagger because the 2 animation (container and scroll) are concurrent: they don't mix, each one try to animate ..going mad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 3**: [snack solution good  for android and ios](https://snack.expo.io/BJqdcLS17)

update: [complete snack with gif like animation](https://snack.expo.io/SkGhRErJm)

I found a workaround for the first partial solution (absolute header with transform translate and contentContainerStyle with paddingTop)

The problem is only on the refresh component, so what to do?

```
const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList)

<AnimatedFlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={item => this._renderRow(item.item, item.index)}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={Animated.event([
          { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollAnim } }, },
        ], { useNativeDriver: true })}
                  refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={() => {
            this.setState({ refreshing: true });
            setTimeout(() => this.setState({ refreshing: false }), 1000);
          }}
          // Android offset for RefreshControl
          progressViewOffset={NAVBAR_HEIGHT}
        />
      }
      // iOS offset for RefreshControl
      contentInset={{
        top: NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
      }}
      contentOffset={{
        y: -NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
      }}

      />
```

This apply offset style on the refreshController, aligning it with the content.

UPDATE2: 
there are some problems on ios.

UPDATE3:
fixed on ios too.

[snack working both ios and android](https://snack.expo.io/BJqdcLS17)

Comment: It works fine. But if I set refreshing: true, then I set refreshing after 2 seconds. The ScrollView scrolled to Y = NAVBAR_HEIGHT

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [react-spring library](https://github.com/drcmda/react-spring) as it supports Parallax effects for react native.

**Update:** A working solution from your example

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Animated, Image, Platform, StyleSheet, View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';

const data = [
  {
    key: 'key',
    name: 'name',
    image: 'imageUrl',
  },
];

const NAVBAR_HEIGHT = 90;
const STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.select({ ios: 20, android: 24 });

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fill: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  navbar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomColor: '#dedede',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    height: NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    color: '#333333',
  },
  row: {
    height: 300,
    width: null,
    marginBottom: 1,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  rowText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const scrollAnim = new Animated.Value(0);

    this._clampedScrollValue = 0;
    this._offsetValue = 0;
    this._scrollValue = 0;

    this.state = {
      scrollAnim,
    };
  }

  _renderRow(rowData, rowId) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Image key={rowId} style={styles.row} source={{ uri: rowData.image }} resizeMode="cover" />
        <Text style={styles.rowText}>{rowData.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { scrollAnim } = this.state;

    const navbarTranslate = scrollAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT],
      outputRange: [0, -(NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT)],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
    const navbarOpacity = scrollAnim.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, NAVBAR_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT],
      outputRange: [1, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.fill}>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            renderItem={item => this._renderRow(item.item, item.index)}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            onScroll={Animated.event([
              { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollAnim } } },
            ])}
          />
        </View>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.navbar, { transform: [{ translateY: navbarTranslate }] }]}>
          <Animated.Text style={[styles.title, { opacity: navbarOpacity }]}>PLACES</Animated.Text>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is not on the animation, but on the hidden refreshcomponent.
In fact i just want to animate the header, without losing the refresh component behind the absolute position header.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem you have, but if you interpolate ScrollView position to header height you can simulate something like the gif in your reference question. It'd be something like this:
```const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, headerScrollDistance],
      outputRange: [headerMaxHeight, headerMinHeight],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });```

Comment: And i did this few days before. But now this animation is laggy. Because you scroll + move the scrollview, and stagger on android
Any idea?

Comment: try to add the `useNativeDriver` prop to the header's `Animated.View`. Also try the animation in release mode, for Android in development mode some animations are always laggy.

Comment: i used transform, and tranforming the parent view of the scroll view, was staggering

Comment: True that, I didn't remember. If you could update the question with some code I'll take a deeper look.

Comment: I added a gif for illustrating it. I found 1 working solution (this one that is staggered) and 1 non working solution (nested scrollview, so you stop scrolling the parent when the header is 0 height. The problem is that you can't do this without touching again and again

Comment: I saw the gif and I've done this on my app, but if I don't see the code I can't say what's wrong.

Comment: added the snack

Comment: I can't see the animation empty data?

Comment: Man try the code, it works. Here you have the updated snack, https://snack.expo.io/HyRGzESk7 but this is the example code you gave.

Comment: I mean, there are no data, so no possible scroll to test

Comment: Have you checked the last snack link? You should view some images with scroll. I can see them on my device

Comment: Oh now it is working! So Just removing the animation from the scroll, make this work. Nice interaction! I will try with diffClam for reproduce the gif animation, good job, thanks

Comment: Great to know. If you could accept the answer it'd be great so if others have the same problem can find a working solution.

Comment: Now i'm on my pc and i can test better. No, sorry. Your solution was identical to mine first solution. If you check it better (just add refreshing and onRefresh) the scroll component is covered by the header, so if you try to refresh, the refreshAnimation will be invisible.


My suggested solution, which use the same base (absolute header with transform) has a custom RefreshComponent for fix this issue.

Comment: how do I put a back button? this one relate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50662474/add-extra-button-to-animated-header

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else falls on this thread, I developed a new package, **react-native-animated-screen**, that does exactly what you need

Check it out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-screen

[image]